# How to get the value of a variable already declared inside a PHP function and return it in the outside

Tags: php, function, variables, scope

```
function count($data) {
    $json = file_get_contents( 'http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&format=json&urls=' . $data . '&pretty=1' );
    $json_data = json_decode($json, true);
    $count = $json_data[0]['total_count'];
    if(empty ($count) ) {
        return 'n/a';
    } else {
        if( $count < 1000 ) return $count;
        $x = round($count);
        $x_number_format = number_format($x);
        $x_array = explode(',', $x_number_format);
        $x_parts = array('k', 'm', 'b', 't');
        $x_count_parts = count($x_array) - 1;
        $x_display = $x;
        $x_display = $x_array[0] . ((int) $x_array[1][0] !== 0 ? '.' . $x_array[1][0] : '');
        $x_display .= $x_parts[$x_count_parts - 1];
        return  $x_display;
    }

}
```

How can I get the value of only `$count` outside of the above function ? calling the above function will definitely return `$x_display` and I want to also echo the simple count `$count` somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return it with `$x_display`. Typically this is done as an array which you can use `list()` to get each piece:

```
function count($data) {
    $json = file_get_contents( 'http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&format=json&urls=' . $data . '&pretty=1' );
    $json_data = json_decode($json, true);
    $count = $json_data[0]['total_count'];
    if(empty ($count) ) {
        return 'n/a';
    } else {
        if( $count < 1000 ) return $count;
        $x = round($count);
        $x_number_format = number_format($x);
        $x_array = explode(',', $x_number_format);
        $x_parts = array('k', 'm', 'b', 't');
        $x_count_parts = count($x_array) - 1;
        $x_display = $x;
        $x_display = $x_array[0] . ((int) $x_array[1][0] !== 0 ? '.' . $x_array[1][0] : '');
        $x_display .= $x_parts[$x_count_parts - 1];
        return  array($x_display, $count);
    }

}

list($x_display, $count) = count($data);
```

Although returning two values is not typically a good practice. Breaking this up into two functions i sprobably the better way to do it:

```
function count($data) {
    $json = file_get_contents( 'http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&format=json&urls=' . $data . '&pretty=1' );
    $json_data = json_decode($json, true);
    return $json_data[0]['total_count'];
}

function getDisplay($count) {
    if(empty ($count) ) {
        return 'n/a';
    } else {
        if( $count < 1000 ) return $count;
        $x = round($count);
        $x_number_format = number_format($x);
        $x_array = explode(',', $x_number_format);
        $x_parts = array('k', 'm', 'b', 't');
        $x_count_parts = count($x_array) - 1;
        $x_display = $x;
        $x_display = $x_array[0] . ((int) $x_array[1][0] !== 0 ? '.' . $x_array[1][0] : '');
        $x_display .= $x_parts[$x_count_parts - 1];
        return  $x_display;
    }
}

$count = count($data);
$x_display = getDisplay($count);
```

Do **not** use the `global` keyword that someone is going to inevitably suggest. That's a **bad** programming practice and can lead to be difficult to detect bugs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! how can I put that ina function? because it actually returns `Array` rather than the count. don't know what is wrong..

Comment: oh didn't see the edit. hold on a second will try that out :)
Thanks!!

Comment: Try the new code I wrote and let me know how that works. If you still get `Array` show the code you used so we can debug it.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I had no idea about such simple way to do that! 
Thanks a lot John :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use for a class in my opinion.

```
class Classname {
  protected $count;

  function getXDisplay() {
    $json = file_get_contents( 'http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&format=json&urls=' . $data . '&pretty=1' );
    $json_data = json_decode($json, true);
    $this->count = $count = $json_data[0]['total_count'];
    if(empty ($count) ) {
       return 'n/a'; // should be null ?
    } else {
       if( $count < 1000 ) return $count;
       $x = round($count);
       $x_number_format = number_format($x);
       $x_array = explode(',', $x_number_format);
       $x_parts = array('k', 'm', 'b', 't');
       $x_count_parts = count($x_array) - 1;
       $x_display = $x;
       $x_display = $x_array[0] . ((int) $x_array[1][0] !== 0 ? '.' . $x_array[1][0] : '');
       $x_display .= $x_parts[$x_count_parts - 1];
       return  $x_display;
    }
  }

  function getCount() {
    if (is_null($this->count)) $this->getXDisplay();
    return $this->count;
  }
}
```

Instead of having messy return values, just call the class method which correlates with the return value.